# How to solve forced scroll-content on ion-content

Tags: scroll, ionic3

[image]

The problem is that If I click the input box to load keyboard layout, map gets attribute `padding-bottom` by the `scroll-content` class but my HTML code doesn't imply to so. 
I put `scroll="false"` and then after, put `fixed-content` on `ion-content` attribute but all failed.

How to solve this problem?

```
<ion-content scroll="false" class="home">

  <div class="upper" id="upper">
```